# Counting a hrefs then subtracting

Tags: javascript, jquery, subtraction

```
$(function() {
 var getName = $('#fa_welcome').text();
 var myName = getName.replace('Welcome ',"");
 var a = $('#recent_topics').find('a[href*="/u"]').filter(':contains("'+myName+'")').length;
 var b = $('#recent_topics').find('a[href*="/u"]').length;
 var c = a-b;
  if(c <= 1) {
  $('.topics_name').append('<div title="'+c+' New Post" id="newTops">'+c+'</div>');
  }
  });
```

Just for randomness I will give you the lengths of var a and b

a= 15
b= 25

I want to subtract these two as in var c

15-25

Though I get -25 parsed?

Any suggestions

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: yah and have you alerted that a,b values..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **parseInt** like

```
var a = parseInt($('#recent_topics').find('a[href*="/u"]').filter(':contains("'+myName+'")').length);
 var b = parseInt($('#recent_topics').find('a[href*="/u"]').length);
```

Comment: And even if *length* was a string, the [subtraction operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) converts the arguments to Number anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you get these values then, use `parseInt` to convert it in `integer`,

```
var c = parseInt(a)-parseInt(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

use parseFloat for getting result

```
$(function() {
 var getName = $('#fa_welcome').text();
 var myName = getName.replace('Welcome ',"");
 var a = parseFloat($('#recent_topics').find('a[href*="/u"]').filter(':contains("'+myName+'")').length);
 var b = parseFloat($('#recent_topics').find('a[href*="/u"]').length);
 var c = a-b;
  if(c <= 1) {
  $('.topics_name').append('<div title="'+c+' New Post" id="newTops">'+c+'</div>');
  }
  });
```